# Fixing prices with and without decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a small issue with my bit of code, it is working but not to the way i want it too.

```js
$('.prices').on('change', function() {
  var elm = $(this).val();
  var value = (elm) ? elm.replace(/\D/, '') : '0';
  $(this).val(($('#amountDeposit').val() == 2) ? parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) : value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="amountDeposit" name="amountDeposit" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Percentage</option>
      <option value="2">Fixed Amount</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="valueDeposit" class="form-control prices" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

2 values in the selection box, percent and fixed amount. If fixed amount then the price is required 2 decimal places in the value.

If fixed amount is selected, and you enter 20 - JQuery changes it to 20.00 - but if you enter 20.00 then JQuery changes it to 2000.00 - The idea of the replace is to remove any symbols the user could enter like £ or %.

I've tried putting the parseFloat in the elm - but it errors when a symbol is in the value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/25xfht1y/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex `/\d+(.\d+)?/` to extract decimal number from user input. Anything else other then decimal digits will be safely removed. You can then use `parseFloat` on match.

Try this

```js
$('.prices').on('change', function() {
  var elm = /\d+(.\d+)?/.exec($(this).val());
  var value = elm ? elm[0] : '0';
  $(this).val(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="amountDeposit" name="amountDeposit" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Percentage</option>
      <option value="2">Fixed Amount</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="valueDeposit" class="form-control prices" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As you don't want to allow floating point if `$(#amountDeposit)` is set to `Percentage`, to do that so use this below snippet.

```
$(this).val(parseFloat(value).toFixed($('#amountDeposit').val() == 2 ? 2 : 0));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, i did add my $(this).val(($('#amountDeposit').val() == 2) ? parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) : value); as percentages does not use decimals.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!